# How to insert slug automatically by tiitle using typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am new in `typeorm`. I am already complete many part in practice. But Now I am facing confused because I am not getting any docs or blogs about creating and updating an unique slug by title in `typeorm`. In `mongoDB`, we get a [mongoose-slug-updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-updater) to automatically create and update slug. But in `typeorm` I am not getting anythings like this.

I am using

```
typeorm (0.3.11)
Postgre (pg- 8.8.0)
Nestjs (9.0.0)
```

Here is my blog entity-

```
@Entity()
export class Blog {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    slug: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    title: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    body: string;
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;
}
```

How can I automatically create and update unique slug. Please help me anyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and update unique slug using typeorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74890287/how-to-create-and-update-unique-slug-using-typeorm)

Comment: I has not any answer? Please check

Comment: I already see this questions, but it has no answer. That's why I place this new question.

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM does not have any ready-made packages like `mongoose-slug-updater`. To create a slug, you can use `@BeforeInsert()` and `@BeforeUpdate()` [entity listeners](https://typeorm.io/listeners-and-subscribers#beforeinsert). You can create your own slug generation logic or use package like [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify).

```
const slugify = require('slugify')

@Entity()
export class Blog {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    slug: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    title: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    body: string;
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;
    
    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    generateSlug() {
      this.slug = slugify(this.title, { lower: true });
    }
}
```

To make slug unique, you can add a random number after the slug or check in async.

```
this.slug = slugify(this.title, { lower: true }) + '-' +  RANDOM_STRING_GENERATING_FUNCTION
```

Comment: But here I want not to add random number if this is the first slug. I mean if title is `this is the title` then slug will be `this-is-the-title`. If then same title come again and again, then I have to append number counting like `this-is-the-title-1`, `this-is-the-title-2`, `this-is-the-title-3`, `this-is-the-title-4`......

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible but you have to write custom logic in the generateSlug() function for that. Find all similar titles, calculate next number and append it.